# Generating a class diagram for iPhone app

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to generate a class diagram for an iPhone application. I wanted to see the flow of the code in a huge application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a "real" UML diagram with all it's features and overhead, you could use a tool like [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/vpuml.jsp?edition=ce). I haven't tested it for Objective C myself but for it worked pretty well for C++/Java/C# and Objective C is supported, according to the website. It also runs on a Mac and the free community-edition should be sufficient for you.

Comment: I have installed VP but not sure how to use it, any idea?

Comment: Oh dear, it's been a while... I remember, that it was pretty easy. I guess, you have create a new project first. Then, search the menubar for something like "synthesize from code". I remember, that it was in a menu which also contained items for specific languages, which are deactivated in the free version. Next to it should be an item called "roundtrip" which will create code from a diagram. Once you've found this option despite my sloppy description, you will be able to add your code-files to VP so it can create a diagram. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the "Quick Model" option in xCode.

1°) Select the project name in xCode (in the left column)

2°) Click on the "Design" menu (after "Run" and before "SCM")

3°) Select "Class Model" => "Quick Model"

It should give you a kind of class diagram for the iPhone App :-)
But be aware it's not completely the class diagram you may know (uml & co).